# How to simplify the following expression in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following:

```
(p^a q (-1 + q^b))/(-p^a q - q^b + p^a q^b + q^(1 + b))
```

I want to do two things:

1) both the numberator and denominator factor out `p` and `q` so that they can cancel

2) force `-1 + q^b` to be shown as `1 - q^b`

3) I also need to simplify the denominator one further step by merging `-q^b+q^(1+b)=q^b(1-q)` since `1-q->p`

Would appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: But `-1 + q^b` is not the same as `1 - q^b` ... imagine `q^b` is 42, for a simple counter.

Comment: but you can multiply both numerator and denominator by -1

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, you could do:

```
expr = (p^a q (-1 + q^b))/(-p^a q - q^b + p^a q^b + q^(1 + b)) //. 
       {x__ (-1 + q ^b) -> -x (1 - q^ b)}
```

Out:

```
-((p^a*q*(1 - q^b))/(-(p^a*q) - q^b + p^a*q^b + q^(1 + b)))
```

As for the first one, I don't see any gain ...

HTH!

**Edit**

Answering your comment:

I'm still not sure what are you trying to achieve with the first tranformation, but here is a try:

```
Numerator@expr/q/Collect[Distribute[Denominator@expr/q], q^(b - 1)]  

(p^a (1 - q^b))/(-p^a + (-1 + p^a) q^(-1 + b) + q^b)
```

[image]

Anyway, I think a warning is a must here: Forcing Mathematica to show results in an "elegant" way can be very tricky for large expressions. I suggest trying to learn how to do it only after you master Mma quite a bit. Then, as a *simple* exercise to get started you may try several ways to force Mma to show

```
-1+a
```

as

```
 a-1
```

Comment: thanks. :) for the first Q, factoring out another p and q from both the denominator and numerator will make the expression look slicker.

Comment: thanks a lot. I haven't really thought about how to force mma to show expressions the way I want it to even though i have used mma for years. could you please list the methods to force mma to show -1+a as a-1, as I really do not know how to. thank you again!

Comment: @Qiang I think that is a very nice question to post as an independent one. Also, you may get better answers than mine by experienced Mma fellow users.